# It it possible to build and IPA without any device connected at any moment?

Tags: xcode, ipa

Having a Apple Developer Membership account and a Mac, it is possible to generate from a Xcode project an IPA file, without connecting a device (iPhone, iPad) at any moment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the Product menu and select "Archive" it will build the app for release on device, regardless if a device is connected or not.

You can then export the API file from the Archives Organizer (Window->Organizer) by selecting the version you just built and clicking "Distribute." You will be asked if the export is for the iTunes store, ad-hoc, etc. and most methods will prompt for a distribution profile to sign the .ipa with.

Comment: Yes, so it is possible. Thanks!